# How to write &#34; instead of &quot; to XML output with XMLStreamWriter/IndentingXMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamwriter

I'm writing data to xml files using com.sun.xml.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter:

> ```
>   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pOutputFile);
>   XMLOutputFactory xmlof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
>   XMLStreamWriter xsw = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(xmlof.createXMLStreamWriter(os));
>
>
>   marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
>   marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
>   marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
>   translationXsdFile.getName());
>   marshaller.setSchema(schema);
>
>   marshaller.marshal(xmlObject, xsw);
>   xsw.close();
> ```

Unforunately, this result in quotes " being encodes as:

> & quot; (space added to show the entity here)

I would like to have it encoded as

> & #34; (space added to show the entity here)

in xml outputfile without parsing it again/replacing the occurence of

> & quot; (space added to show the entity here)